# Controls get blurry and hidden in storyboard in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

My controls got blurry when saw in hierarchy of view controllers of storyboard and hidden from actual view controller but when i run the code they are showing well on the simulator and real device. Please help me that how i can re-activate or show my hidden controls and they are also not hidden by inspector.

Please see the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzPkK.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because those views are not made in the **size class** `any-any`. Change the size class at the bottom to the one you originally created when you designed those views and they will appear normal again.